# When rendering a list of items in React, how to treat a new item, that doesn't have an ID yet?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have some component that renders a simple list of items, fetched from some API:

```
{this.state.items.map((item) => {
    return (
       <div key={item.id}>
          <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
          <p>Age: {item.price}</p>
       </div>
      )
})}
```

The id is used as a unique key, as it's usually done.

But what if i have some functionality of adding empty "item" models, to be filled by the user, and then submitted to the server? This object **wouldn't have an ID yet**, being that the server generates the ID. I of course assume here that there isn't any separate state and UI to treat the form, and it's all part of the same "items" array(all fields are editable).

Let's assume that i do not want to perform any ajax request, until the user has "added" a batch of items. How would i treat the absence of id's, when it comes to the list key, being that it would be undefined? Should a temporary ID be assigned?(which in my opinion can lead bugs).

I know that using the index is a very bad practice, being that it can lead to unexpected behavior during sorting and reordering.

What is the conventional way of tackling this issue?

EDIT: Why am i concerned about generating temporary random id's?

Imagine that an item can also be edited(meaning the changes are also submitted to some /update endpoint). The endpoint requires an ID as a parameter, of course. **What happens if a user edits(and submits) an item that wasn't actually created yet on the server?**. The server will receive an ID that doesn't exist. This means that i would need to present some logic on the front-end, that makes sure this scenario is impossible.

Also keep in mind that the ID needs to "stable", being that the uniqueness of the item depends on it. What happens if the same item receives a new ID from the server? This would require me to make sure i refresh the entire list of items with another /get ajax request(which i usually do).

I think that performing another /get ajax(or just another query that returns the new list) after every create/update ajax takes care of all scenarios, but this of course leads to some overhead, both on the front-end and on the server.

Comment: How about using a hash function to create temporary ids ? After the user has their items "ready", the hash-ids can be replaced after a server-request. You can also just use a random number generator.

Comment: I think temp id's can have some caveats. Please read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use some kind of a random number or hash generator to create temporary ids which can be replaced via a server request when the user is "ready" with their item creation.

Comment: As far as understand, your big concern is "What happens if a user edits(and submits) an item that wasn't actually created yet on the server?"But how can you edit something which has not been created yet on the server side?

Comment: Well you're right, but let's say my UI is rather "dumb", and presents an "update" button for each item. The user then can forget that it's a fresh item, and press the update button, or just perform a "batch" update on all items(that depends of course on how i implement things. Additional logic is needed here).  The bottom line is, that i foresee some possible pitfalls :D

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have your items-from-api list with your new items. You can show them together but they should be different state variables, so it's easier to post them to your server and differentiating.

As for which key to use, I would just identify it with something like `temporary-list-item-${i}` or similar. It's meant to be a temporary item, after creating it you will delete the temp list from state and just use the api's response (which should generate an id for each item created), so these temp keys will be gone. But hey, this is only my vision of it, there are tons of other ways to solve it.

Comment: Well i try to avoid duplicating state, because it make things a bit convoluted. Also, imagine that my list UI allows me to insert a new item in between two other items, instead of the end of the list. How would i "merge" the two lists, while keeping their order?

Comment: It wouldn't be duplicate, just one for the api's response and other for new items. As for the inserting in between, you will surely need more logic than what I suggest. You can probably keep one state variable and save the indexes of new items so when you post to your api you know which items should be new.  As for the key, I stand by the 'temporary-list-item' ond